Calling an ASP.NET Core Web API integrated to EntraId app from another .NET Core console app integrated to EntraId app fails
I have created an ASP.NET Core Web API and registered it in EntraID and configured it in my program.cs as follows:
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

Then I have registered another app in the EntraId and configured the code in the console application as follows:
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
               .Create(appId)
               .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
               .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
               .Build();

var result = app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"api://{apiAppId}/.default" })
               .ExecuteAsync();

result.Wait();

var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.Result.AccessToken);

var response = client.GetAsync(endpointUrl);
            response.Wait();


Further, I also configured the app registration with a scope named "xxx.read" and added the client application under the Authorized clent applications of Expose an API settings.
When the console application calls the web api, web api throws the following error.

Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDW10201: Neither scope nor roles claim was found in the bearer token. Authentication scheme used: 'Bearer'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDW10201: Neither scope nor roles claim was found in the bearer token. Authentication scheme used: 'Bearer'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware[0]
Policy authentication schemes  did not succeed
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware: Debug: Policy authentication schemes  did not succeed
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService2
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.



Am I missing anything?

As you are making use of ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder make sure to create app roles and grant admin consent to the App roles.

Thanks Rukmini, app roles in client app?

No, as delegated API permissions do not work for ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder you have to expose an API and create an App role in the API app and grant admin consent for that app role in the client app. Check this for detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79173218/azure-ad-client-credentials-generated-token-does-not-have-claims-edited/79174116#79174116

Did you get a chance to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79173218/azure-ad-client-credentials-generated-token-does-not-have-claims-edited/79174116#79174116 @Jana

Many thanks @Rukmini, it worked.

Can I post an answer in detail?

Yes, please post the answer.


Note that: Delegated API permissions work only for user interactive flow. As you are making use of  ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder you need to create app roles and grant application type API permissions.

In the API application, expose an API and create app role:

In the RukAppClient application, grant API permission:

Generate the token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id : ClientID
scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret : ClientSecret
grant_type : client_credentials


When decoded the role claim will be present in the token successfully:


A delegated permission is only used when a user is involved in the authentication. In your case only the app is there. So you need an app role / application permission. That one will be in the roles claim of the token.

Thank Juunas, The token with the above configuration is not returning any roles. Should I do any additional configuration in the EntraID?
